# Otsu Thresholding and Image gradient orientation

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I want to apply Otsu thresholding to image  gradients (to remove noise). After that, I want to compute the gradients orientation. Unfortunately, when I do so, I only get gradient orientations between 0 and 90 degrees. Without Otsu thresholding, the values are between 0 and 360.

See my code in Python

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Ob.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = img.astype('float32')
img2 = 
dst1 = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)
dst2 = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)

ret1,th1 = cv2.threshold(dst1.astype(np.uint8),0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
ret2,th2 = cv2.threshold(dst2.astype(np.uint8),0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(dst1.astype(np.float32),dst2.astype(np.float32))
np.rad2deg(ang)
```

Comment: You do understand that thresholding implies setting the values to either 0 or 1, right? Now all your gradient vectors are either [0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], etc. Of course their directions are quantized to the nearest 45 degrees. Thresholding is not meant to remove noise. Try smoothing instead!

Comment: @Cris Luengo sincerely sorry for that but please check what is the sobel filter (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) and what the OpenCV's thresholding flag does correspond to (https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Comment: @John_Sharp1318: why are you giving me these links? I'm not sure why what I wrote is not a clear explanation of the problem OP is having.

Comment: the second link opencv threshold function If the the flag THRESH_TRUNC is not use return a matrix with values between 0-255 if the flag THRESH_TRUNC is use the range become 0 - the value of the image.
It is also written as in in the documentation.
The reason why it like the come from the fact that opencv do not support boolean natively they are casted into uint8 matrices. Basically threshold return a mask.
The first link it was because the masks you wrote does not correspond to any gradient operator but reading your answer I understand they were not gradient mask but orientation one Sorry.

Comment: @John_Sharp1318: Ah, OK, so OpenCV uses 0 and 255, not 0 and 1. I always forget that, thanks. I’ve fixed my answer.

Comment: Or 0-the value of the original image if THRESH_TRUNC is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening in your code is quite simple to explain:

`dst1` and `dst2`, the output of the two Sobel filters, are the x and y components of the gradient vector. For one given pixel, the gradient vector is given by (`dst1[i,j]`, `dst2[i,j]`). This vector can have any values, for example (5.8,-2.1), leading to an angle of about 340 degrees.

Next, you threshold these two images. Otsu thresholding will find a value for which the image is nicely separated into pixels of low intensity and pixels of high intensity. These are assigned values of 0 and 255, respectively. But first, you convert the floating-point images to uint8, setting all negative values to 0. So, our vector (5.8,-2.1) is first converted to (5,0), and then thresholded, after which it becomes either (255,0) or (0,0) depending on what side of the threshold the 5 falls.

Thus, we have converted the vector with an angle of 340 degrees to one with an angle of 0 degrees or no computable angle (though `atan2(0,0)` typically yields 0 also).

In fact, all vectors have become either (0,0), (0,255), (255,0) or (255,255), meaning that you will only find angles of 0, 45 and 90 degrees.

What you should do instead is compute the magnitude, and threshold that (I don't know if Otsu is the ideal method for such an image). Next, use only the angle for those pixels where the magnitude is above the threshold.

Another common alternative is to use Gaussian gradients instead of Sobel. There, you can set a smoothing (regularization) parameter, which allows you to remove more or less noise. I often see this implemented as a Gaussian blur followed by the Sobel filters, though it makes more sense to me to directly use Gaussian derivative filters.

Answer (score 2):

If I may why the first thing you do is to convert the data to float32 ?

I think it would be more efficient to just let it does during the Sobel processing.
That is just my point of view.

The thing you named "noise" as result of the gradient filter is actually called non maxima.
Oftenly algorithm such as Canny does consist to threshold it after the [Sobel](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html) filtering.
The inconvenient with this approach is to find the appropriate thresholds.
Personally I use the non maxima suppression of [another](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d54/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1StructuredEdgeDetection.html) algorithm.

Your code would become:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('Ob.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

dx,dy = cv2.spatialGradient(img,ksize=5)

mag = cv2.magnitude(dx.astype(np.float32),dy.astype(np.float32))

se = cv2.ximgproc_StructuredEdgeDetection()

ori = se.computeOrientation(mag)

edges_without_nms = se.edgesNms(mag,ori)
```

I hope it helps you.